# Testing an Attachment Inserted via Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, attachment, code-coverage

I am trying to get test coverage for a method in a controller extension. As part of my "Pagereference Save()" method, I am creating an attachment and trying to insert it with a try/catch block as shown below. Addtionally, I have added the getAttachedFile method I have created from earlier in the class:

```
public Attachment getAttachedFile(){
    attachedFile = New Attachment();
    return attachedFile;

}

public pagereference Save() {

Attachment a = new Attachment(ParentId = supportCase.Id, name = attachedFile.Name, body = attachedFile.Body);    

        try{
        insert a; 
        }
        catch(DMLException except){
            String mg = except.getMessage();
            if (mg.contains('Body') && mg.contains('Name')){
                isThereFile = false;
            }
            else{ 

            ApexPages.addMessage(New ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 'It seems there was an issue with you attachment. Please ensure that it is below the file size limit of 25 MB'));
            PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
              return pageRef;
            }
}
```

In my test class, in one of the test methods, I create a case, insert it, and additionally run both methods from the controller as shown below:

```
Test.startTest();

    Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'testingAccount');
    insert testAccount;

    Case cs = new Case(accountId = testAccount.Id, subject='test', Protocol_Issue__c = 'requred issue', Protocol_Sub_Issue__c = 'reuired sub issue', SuppliedPhone = '1111111111', suppliedEmail= 'testemail@testttest.net', SuppliedName = 'Tim Test', Description = 'testDescription' );
    insert cs;

    ApexPages.StandardController ctlr   = new ApexPages.StandardController(cs);
    ControllerExtension controller = new ControllerExtension(ctlr);


    PageReference createdObject = controller.Save();

    cs.SuppliedPhone = '1234567891123y';

    Attachment attach = controller.getAttachedFile();

    Test.StopTest();
```

Is it possible to change or append the test method so that the Attachemnt code in the "Save()" method gets covered?

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor `save()` method as follows not only get the coverage, but also for actual testing.

```
public Integer attachmentBodyLength =0;

public pagereference Save() {
Attachment a = new Attachment(ParentId = supportCase.Id, name = attachedFile.Name, body = attachedFile.Body);   

try{
    if(Test.isRunningTest()){
        attachmentBodyLength = 10; //any length you can put which can be tested
    }
    else{
        attachmentBodyLength = 26214400; //25MB, Salesforce limit
    }
    System.debug('a.BodyLength=' + a.BodyLength);
if(a.BodyLength>attachmentBodyLength)
{
    throw new myCustomException('It seems there was an issue with you attachment. Please ensure that it is below the file size limit of 25 MB');
}

insert a;
return null; 
}
catch(DMLException except)
    {
        String mg = except.getMessage();
        System.debug(mg);
        if (mg.contains('Body') && mg.contains('Name'))
        {
            isThereFile = false;                
        }
        return null;
    }            
 catch(Exception e)
   {
      ApexPages.addMessage(New ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error, e.getMessage()));
      PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
      return pageRef;
   }
}
}
```

> Now from your test class create 2 scenarios for testing the insert attachment exception.

1. Create an attachment record with either name or body as null. And during insertion it will throw the `DMLException`.
2. Create an attachment with `bodyLength` greater that `attachmentBodyLength` (which has been specified in Controller) and it will throw `CustomException`, which will be caught in the `Exception` block.

This approach just came to my mind to get rid of creating 25MB attachments.

Refer [apex testing best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm) for writing test classes.